# регулярные выражения php [Экранирование спец символов]

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
$reg_exp = "/abc\\\\e/";
$reg_exp2 = "/abc\\\a/";
echo preg_match($reg_exp, "abc\\e"); /// Это первый пример если что ^_^
echo preg_match($reg_exp2, "abc\\a"); /// Если в конце поставить букву e как в первом примере выражение станет ложным WHY?
```

Выведет единицу и там и там, но почему? В первом примере понятно, там 2 раза экранируем, а во втором примере не пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чтобы использовать одинарную кавычку внутри строки, проэкранируйте ее обратной косой чертой (). Если необходимо написать саму обратную косую черту, продублируйте ее (\). Все остальные случаи применения обратной косой черты будут интерпретированы как обычные символы: это означает, что если вы попытаетесь использовать другие управляющие последовательности, такие как \r или \n, они будут выведены как есть вместо какого-либо особого поведения.
>
> Если строка заключена в двойные кавычки ("), PHP распознает большее количество управляющих последовательностей для специальных символов:
>
> Как и в строке, заключенной в одинарные кавычки, экранирование любого символа выведет также и саму обратную косую черту. До версии PHP 5.1.1, обратная косая черта в {$var} не печаталась.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

При возникновении «ошибок» связанных с экранированием в любом ЯП всегда делайте вывод текста и смотрите что фактически получается в строке.

```
echo "/abc\\\a/"
```

Comment: Вот так выведет ***echo "/abc\a/" -> /abc\a/***

"Если необходимо написать саму обратную косую черту, продублируйте ее (\\)" - выходит не надо ничего дублировать

Comment: Есть набор последовательностей, которые экранируются: список есть по ссылке. Символы, которых нет в этом списке не будут экранироваться и обратная косая черта выступит в роли литерала, а не спецсимвола экранирования.

Comment: получается ***"\\\a"*** - первый слеш заэкранирует второй и исчезнет, второй останется, а с третьим что тогда, не до конца понял
На выходе будет : ***\\a***

Comment: Первый слэш экран для второго. На выходе- один слэш. Третий слэш не может быть экраном для «а»: литерала «а» нет в списке, а значит третий слэш и «а» на выходе дадут слэш и «а». Два литерала.

Comment: все спасибо, разобрался